# WordPress Media Library Grid View Not Working

Tags: wordpress

images are now shown in grid view but it shown in listed view

[image]

Images shown in grid view also in wordpress admin panel

Comment: check in ajax error

Comment: How ? will you please elaborate i am newbie

Comment: Go network Tab in developer tool and check ajax call response